# Unable to install newly created Android App

Tags: android, eclipse, new-operator, adt

I am a newbie to Android world and started learning it few days back. I developed a sample application Using Eclipse and ADT pluggin. Checked it on Emulator, it's working. But when I exported that App as *.apk and tried to install it in my phone (Samsung Galaxy S running 2.2) ... it gives error that "Application not installed"

Can somebody throw some light on this ?

Answer (score 2):

If the one on your device is signed with another key (e.g., debug), you
won't be able to install the other one over the top. You're not allowed to replace an application with another that has a conflicting signature. Uninstall the old APK, then try again.

Comment: I'm trying to install it for the first time. It's the first sample app from Professional Android 2 Application Development book

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie too & i had the same issue.Just uninstalled the previous app, and freshly exported a new apk file with keystore information. Then i was able to install it the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable "Unknown Sources" in the Applications Settings menu on your phone?

Comment: yes. It tries to install ... shows progress bar, but then the error